# Different Error messages between database on heroku and local one

Tags: node.js, heroku, sequelize.js, psql

i got the following problem:

I am using sequelize to create my model.
When i am depolying it to heroku i get my custom error message that i defined with sequelize

```
var User = connection.define(
    "user",
    {
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: {
                args: true,
                msg: "Username already taken"
            },
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: {
                args: true,
                msg: "Email already taken"
            },
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                isEmail: {
                    args: true,
                    msg: "Invalid email"
                }
            }
        },
```

When my application is live on heroku i get this error message "Username already taken" when i try to create users with same username in my error handling "try catch block"
But when i try this on my local machine this custom error message doesnt work.

minimum example code:

```
try {
  var user = await sequelize.models.user.create(args);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("createUser error:", error);            
}
```

when i run my code locally i get following output from this console.log():

```
createUser error: { SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: doppelter Schlüsselwert verletzt Unique-Constraint »users_username_key«
at Query.formatError (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:328:16)
at query.catch.err (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:86:18)
at tryCatcher (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
at _drainQueue (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/whatever/NodeApps/MyStuff/testapp/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at processImmediate (timers.js:637:19)
name:'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
errors: {},
fields: undefined,
```

on heroku i get this one:

```
createUser error: { SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Username already taken
at Query.formatError (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:325:18)
at query.catch.err (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:86:18)
at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
at _drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at processImmediate (timers.js:637:19)
name: 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError',
errors:
[ ValidationErrorItem {
message: 'Username already taken',
type: 'unique violation',
path: 'username',
value: 'testuser',
origin: 'DB',
instance: [user],
validatorKey: 'not_unique',
validatorName: null,
validatorArgs: [] } ],
fields: { username: 'testuser' },
```

so in comparison the **error** object is **empty** and the **fields** is **undefined**

i just commited all my code to heroku again to make sure my local code matches the one thats running on heroku.

Now i am wondering why my custom message doesn't work with my local database. If you need more information let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the difference of the line numbers in the two tracebacks, it sounds like you have different versions of the `sequelize` library locally and in Heroku:

Locally, you have the failure raised at:

```
...sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:328:18
```

In Heroku, at:

```
...sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:325:18
```

This suggests these are not the same versions of the library -- you might consider try to update it locally, or somehow ensuring to install the same version in both places.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already found out the answer by myself. In case you are interested in: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10559
In short it was a problem with my local language/local settings of postgres.